# merge lines starting with a pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'm trying to learn about sed, grep and awk, and I'm facing the folowing problem: I have the folowing log after use sed to get all lines between two patterns (START and END):

```
START
tag: text info text text info text
    text info texttext info text
    text info texttext info text
    text info texttext info text

other_tag: text info text text info text
    text info text text info text text info text
    text info text text info text text info text
END
START
tag: text info text text info text
    text info text text info text
    text info text text info text
other_tag: text info text text info text
    text info text text info text text info text
    text info text text info text text info text
END
```

I would like to merge all lines to their parent, removing the starting [tab], like that:

```
START
tag: text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text
other_tag: text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text
END
START
tag: text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text
other_tag: text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text text info text
END
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: For a `sed` solution, see for example [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "=".** (replace `=` by `\t`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might should go on using **sed**. Use **N** could append the next line of input into the pattern space, then you can match the **\n** between two line.

You can refer to:

```
sed ':a; N; $!b a; s/\n\s\{1,\}/ /g'
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works perfectly! I'm still trainning sed reading and practicing lots of tutorials! thanks!